# Variant of linear regression using perpendicular distance instead of vertical

Tags: regression

Normally, linear regression asks for a pair of parameters m,b such that for a set of given points $\{x_i,y_i\}$ the variance of $y-m\cdot x-b$ is minimized (this minimizes the distance in y-direction only).

Instead, I would like to find a line $y'=m\cdot x'+b$ such that the pairs $(x_i,y_i)$ have minimal **perpendicular** distance from that line.

I strongly suspect that the parameters (m,b) turn out to be the same in either case, but I can't find anything on the web, and when I tried the calculation by myself I found me totally out of practice with one error for each 3 lines of my calculations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With appropriate method names, you will be able to find a lot of references: you seem to be looking for [Deming regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression), orthogonal regression, orthogonal distance regression (ODR), errors-in-variables (EIV) modeling, or more often [total least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares) (TLS). It is illustrated below in the bivariate case:

[image]

The model was originally introduced by R. J. Adcock, 1878, [A problem in least squares](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2635758), refined by C. H. Kummell, 1879, [Reduction of observation equations which contain more than one observed quantity](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2635646), and revived by W. E. Deming, 1943, [Statistical adjustment of data](http://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/statistical-adjustment-of-data).

Comment: Thank you for providing the magic word "Deming regression" that opens googles vault of wisdom.

Comment: Plenty to help you rederive the required three lines of calculations!